# Read a pickled dictionary Python

Tags: python, pickle

I'm working with a pickled file in Python, and I need to extract the data from it. The data was saved as a dictionary:

I read it

```
import pickle

data  = pickle.load( open("MyData.p", "rb") )
```

I read one dictionary:

```
data[0]

[{'StartTime': '2018-04-01 11:11:28',
  'Name': 'AA',
  'StudyName': '2018{AF4}',
  'Data': [(10829.162109375,
    13013.4033203125),
   (11050.34375,
    13063.3125),
   (11514.7509765625,
    13103.005859375)],
  'Times': (5514.899,
   5542.091,
   5952.291),
  'startOffset': 0.0}]
```

and get all the fields and can see it if printed. One of the fields is called "StartTime". However, when I want to access the field says

```
data[0]["StartTime"]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Same with all fields. 
How can I access the fields individually?

Comment: You are going to have to show more of you data.

Comment: Just edited, thanks!

Comment: you're almost there, try `data[0][0]['StartTime']`. The error occurred because `data[0]` is a list containing one dictionary.

Comment: The error you get kinda already shows you the problem. It tells you that you are trying to index a list, but you expect a dict there. Therefore, the first thing you want to do is check what `data[0]` gives you and why it is a list and not the expected dict.
Just wanting to teach a little bit of how to do debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just pretty print the data to see what you got:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(data)
```

In your specific case, try this:

```
print(data[0][0]["StartTime"])
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that is it!
I'll accept this answer because it was posted first.

Answer (score 0):

There is another list you need to select the 0 element from.

data[0][0]["StartTime"]